# `listpw` Default option not working with sudo 1.8.24

Tags: sudo

I'm using `sudo` 1.8.24 on arch linux (just the default version that comes with the OS), and running into problems where it prompts me for my password just to list that a command is valid.  Here is my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
Defaults rootpw
Defaults listpw=never
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/false ""
```

I'm in the wheel group.  The documentation leads me to believe that `listpw=never` means I should never be prompted for a password when running `sudo -l`, and that anyway the default should be to allow it if I don't require a password for `/bin/false`.

Unfortunately, when I run `sudo -l /bin/false`, it prompts me for my own password.  Note that `sudo /bin/false` does not require a password, and `sudo` anything else prompts for the root password, but `sudo -l` anything prompts for my password.  This is particularly annoying if I have already typed the root password to run something as root, as I still have to type my own password two seconds later when running `sudo -l`.  (This is a pattern often used by scripts, that check if you have permission before running `sudo`, causing me to be prompted for a password even when `sudo` would succeed without requesting a password.)

**update**

When I run `sudo -l`, I get prompted for my password, then sudo prints:

```
Matching Defaults entries for user on machine:
    rootpw, listpw=never, timestamp_timeout=60, env_keep+=HOME

User user may run the following commands on machine:
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/false
```

Also I've since upgraded to sudo 1.8.25 and still see the problem, so I've basically given up and concluded that this is a bug in sudo.

Comment: Yes, I'm in the wheel group, and therefore can execute /bin/false with no password and anything else with the root password.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this; if you run `sudo -l` as the user, are there other "Matching Defaults entries" that show up?

Comment: @JeffSchaller See my update.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I can also reproduce this on 1.8.27, but it's [fixed in 1.8.28](https://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=869)

If you remove the `listpw=never` entry, your `ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/false` line will trigger the acceptance rule and `sudo -l` will stop prompting for a password.