# How to enable password-less listing of sudo permissions (`sudo -l`) without adding `sudo -l` to /etc/sudoers?

Tags: linux, debian, sudo

I want all users to be able to view their `sudo` permissions without entering their password.

Is there any way to allow this without adding `ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -l` to `/etc/sudoers`?

```
bob@cad50ee0931e:/$ sudo -l

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for bob:
```

Comment: Related - [`listpw` Default option not working with sudo 1.8.24](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/466326/100397)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for the `sudoers` file (`man sudoers`) offers these suggestions

> By default, `sudo` requires that a user authenticate him or herself before running a command. [...] if the `NOPASSWD` tag is applied to *any* of the entries for a user on the current host, he or she will be able to run `sudo -l` without a password. This behavior may be overridden via the [...] `listpw` options.

and

> **`listpw`** This option controls when a password will be required when a user runs `sudo` with the `-l` option. It has the following possible values:
>
> - `all` - All the user's `sudoers` entries for the current host must have the `NOPASSWD` flag set to avoid entering a password
> - `always` - The user must always enter a password to use the `-l` option.
> - `any` - At least one of the user's `sudoers` entries for the current host must have the `NOPASSWD` flag set to avoid entering a password.
> - `never` - The user need never enter a password to use the `-l` option.

Assuming you want to avoid `NOPASSWD`, you would set `listpw=never`:

```
Defaults listpw=never
```

Use `visudo` to edit and check the `sudoers` file (tip: use `EDITOR=nano visudo` if you want to use `nano` to edit the `sudoers file instead of`vi`). Better still, keep another root shell open while you test so that you don't lose access.

---

Unfortunately, it seems that [a bug in `sudo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/466326/100397), which is [fixed in 1.8.28](https://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=869), may ignore the `listpw=never` setting. In this scenario you *must not* use `listpw=never`, but instead create an otherwise meaningless entry such as this

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/false
```

The net result should be that `sudo -l` will trigger on the *any entry has `NOPASSWD`* rule and you will achieve your requirement.

Comment: You are absolutely right. In my case `NOPASSWD` didnt't work, if `listpw=never` was enabled. I'm running `sudo 1.8.27` and `listpw=never` didn't work. Do you know, when a corrected `sudo` is released for Debian, or how to download a corrected version using `apt-get`?